# How to insert into tkinter Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to insert a txt file read variable into the tkinter Text widget, but, I'm having this error: `_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!toplevel"`

Check out my code:

```
textInfo = tk.Text(accountPopup, width=40, height=10, font=("Helvetica", 12))
            textInfo.pack(pady=20)

            path = './Contas/Info/'+txtName+'.txt'

            textFile = open(path , 'r')
            readedText = textFile.read()

            finalRead = str(readedText)

            textInfo.insert(tk.END, finalRead)
```

Comment: You destroyed a `tk.Toplevel` widget (probably accountPopup) and you are trying to use it as a `master`. Your code does not reflect this issue, but that's what you did.

Comment: I think the button I had put on tk was destroying the popup, but now everything is fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `tk.END` and not `END` simply because your import is `import tkinter as tk`, so you should suffix `END` with `tk`. Also you could say `'end'` instead of `tk.END`.

So to conclude:

```
tk.END #import tkinter as tk
END #from tkinter import *
'end' #you can use this with any of the above type of imports
```

Hope this cleared your error, do let me know if any more doubts or errors.

Cheers

Comment: Hey, Cool Cloud, I updated the question, can you help me?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the error, and new programmers are always importing tkinter 3 different ways so, the chances are that `END` was actually covered. As-well-as `tk.END`, `tkinter.END`, whatever the python 2 way of doing it was, and all of it one more time for good measure. LOL!

Comment: @MichaelGuidry actually this was the initial solve to his problem, that worked, he updated the Q again with another error he got.